# Adding resources to classpath in kotlin/java/spring boot, using gradle as build tool

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, gradle, kotlin

I'm trying to add `import.sql` from resources to classpath so it gets loaded by hibernate and some test data gets imported into database when application is starting.

I'm using kotlin and gradle with following plugins:

- jvm
- plugin.spring
- plugin.jpa
- org.springframework.boot
- io.spring.dependency-management

When running application from IntelliJ (`bootRun` task), resources are located in `build/resources/main` and java classes are located in `build/classes/java/main`. So when hibernate tries to load the import.sql it can't be found since java classpath is in `build/classes/java/main` (tried to run `getResources("")` and it returned that folder). Generated folder structure, application.properties and gradle build can be found below.

[image: generated build folder structure]

`application.properties`

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.*=TRACE
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=trace
spring.datasource.data=classpath://import.sql

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/console
```

`build.gradle.kts`

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

val kotlinVersion = "1.3.50"
val springBootVersion = "2.1.9.RELEASE"
val h2Version = "1.4.200"
val hibernateVersion = "5.4.6.Final"
val snippetsDir = "./build/generated-snippets"
val test = "./gradle/test"

group = "org.testkotlin"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java{
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}

repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    mavenCentral()
}

extra["snippetsDir"] = file(snippetsDir)

plugins {
    idea
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.50"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.50"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.3.50"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.1.9.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.8.RELEASE"
    id("org.asciidoctor.convert") version "1.5.8"
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.hibernate:hibernate-core:$hibernateVersion")
    runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2:$h2Version")
    annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

tasks.test {
    outputs.dir(snippetsDir)
}

tasks.asciidoctor {
    inputs.dir(snippetsDir)
    dependsOn(test)
}

tasks.bootRun {
    doFirst {
        classpath = files("$buildDir/classes/main", "$buildDir/resources/main")
    }
}
```

So my questions are:

- How to add resources to classpath ?
- Is it possible to modify `bootRun` task to do this (doFirst is not an option since task relies on `classes/java` not existing beforehand) ?
- Is there some property inside `bootRun` or gradle build which enables this ?
- Ultimately how can i get hibernate to automatically recognize `import.sql` without manually moving it to `build/classes/java/main` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining your resource folder correctly, and Gradle with the Spring Boot plugin will automatically add it to the classpath. If that didn't happen, Spring would also not be able to load your `application.properties` file either, which I assume it does.

I also assume that you want to use Hibernate to load your data, as that is the default behavior if you have a file called `import.sql`. But it only does this if the `ddl-auto` property is set to `create` or `create-drop`, and yours is `update`.

You could also let Spring Boot handle the datasource initialization instead of Hibernate, but you it will still only happen when the schema is (re-)created, and not when just connecting to it.

Also, even though this is not the cause of your problems, I don't believe classpath resources in Spring should be prefixed with slash, but at the very least not two (`classpath://import.sql`).

Comment: Had to refresh gradle dependencies, reimport gradle project, change to create or create-drop and then it worked as intended, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First things first - resources in Spring Boot should be placed in `src/main/resources` folder, not `build/classes/java/main`. `build` packages are product of `bootRun` task and will change every time when you will run it.

Looking into Spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.2.0.M2/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-intialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc):

> Spring Boot enables it by default and loads SQL from the standard locations schema.sql and data.sql (in the root of the classpath).

It means that Spring looks for `import.sql` file in root of the classpath (resources folder). In IntelliJ it looks like this:

[image: IntelliJ resources folder]

Comment: Resources from src/main/resources are copied to build/resources/main by default when running gradle build task - I didn’t copy them manually there.

Comment: You should also remove property `spring.datasource.data=classpath://import.sql` from application.properties

Comment: Have you got repository on Github with this project? I could try to clone it and run it locally to see what is wrong.